# JavaScript code doesn't run even if Safari Web Inspector shows no errors at all

Tags: javascript, fonts, blob, filereader

So I've been working on a simple HTML document to generate iOS and iPadOS configuration profiles using the following JavaScript script:

```
async function configAndDownloadProfile() {
    // Get the font's PostScript name (for example, NewYorkMedium-Regular.otf) from index.html
    var fontPostScriptName = document.getElementById("font-postscript-name").value;
        if (fontPostScriptName === "null") {
            alert("Invalid input or no input provided!");
            return;
        };

    // Get the font's full name (for example, New York Medium Regular) from index.html
    var fontFullName = document.getElementById("font-full-name").value;
        if (fontFullName === "null") {
            alert("Invalid input or no input provided!");
            return;
        };

    // Get the font file from index.html
    var fontFile = document.getElementById("font-file").files;
        if (fontFile === "null") {
            alert("Invalid input or no input provided!");
            return;
        };

    var fileExtension = fontPostScriptName.split(".").pop();
        if (fileExtension === "ttf") {
            var blob = new Blob([fontFile], {type: "font/ttf"});
        } else if (fileExtension = "otf") {
            var blob = new Blob([fontFile], {type: "font/otf"});
        } else {
            alert("Invalid input or no input provided!");
            return;
        };

        var reader = new FileReader()

    // Create a new UUID (with totally non-RFC 4122 version 4 random bytes but at least it works)
    function generateUUID() {
        return Math.floor((Math.random() * 100000000) + 1000) + "-" + Math.floor((Math.random() * 10000) + 1000) + "-" + Math.floor((Math.random() * 10000) + 1000) + "-" + Math.floor((Math.random() * 10000) + 1000) + "-" + Math.floor((Math.random() * 1000000000000) + 100000000000);
    };

    var firstUUID = generateUUID();

    var secondUUID = generateUUID();

    var thirdUUID = generateUUID();

    // Configuration profile contents
    var configurationProfile = `<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
\t<key>ConsentText</key>
\t<dict>
\t\t<key>default</key>
\t\t<string>To manage installed fonts, go to Settings.</string>
\t</dict>
\t<key>PayloadContent</key>
\t<array>
\t\t<dict>
\t\t\t<key>Font</key>
\t\t\t<data>
\t\t\t` + reader.readAsDataURL(blob) + `
\t\t\t</data>
\t\t\t<key>Name</key>
\t\t\t<string>` + fontPostScriptName + `</string>
\t\t\t<key>PayloadDescription</key>
\t\t\t<string>Configures Font settings</string>
\t\t\t<key>PayloadDisplayName</key>
\t\t\t<string>Fonts</string>
\t\t\t<key>PayloadIdentifier</key>
\t\t\t<string>com.apple.font.` + firstUUID + `</string>
\t\t\t<key>PayloadType</key>
\t\t\t<string>com.apple.font</string>
\t\t\t<key>PayloadUUID</key>
\t\t\t<string>` + firstUUID + `</string>
\t\t\t<key>PayloadVersion</key>
\t\t\t<integer>1</integer>
\t\t</dict>
\t</array>
\t<key>PayloadDescription</key>
\t<string>This configuration profile lets you use fonts downloaded from the web in documents you create on iOS and iPadOS.</string>
\t<key>PayloadDisplayName</key>
\t<string>` + fontFullName + `</string>
\t<key>PayloadIdentifier</key>
\t<string>Toms-MacBook-Air.` + secondUUID + `</string>
\t<key>PayloadOrganization</key>
\t<string>Apple Inc.</string>
\t<key>PayloadRemovalDisallowed</key>
\t<false/>
\t<key>PayloadType</key>
\t<string>Configuration</string>
\t<key>PayloadUUID</key>
\t<string>` + thirdUUID + `</string>
\t<key>PayloadVersion</key>
\t<integer>1</integer>
</dict>
</plist>
`

    // Configuration profile installer
    function downloadProfile(fontPostScriptName, configurationProfile) {
        blob = new Blob([configurationProfile], {type: "application/x-apple-aspen-config"});
        var a = document.createElement("a");
        a.download = fontPostScriptName + ".mobileconfig";
        a.href = window.URL.createObjectURL(blob);
        a.click()
    };
}
```

All it does is Base64 encode the font files the user submits just to put them inside a `.mobileconfig` file downloadable by whoever submitted said font file. Safari Web Inspector isn't showing any errors and everything seems to be fine, but whenever someone clicks the Download Profile button (`<input type="button" onclick="configAndDownloadProfile()" value="Download Profile">`) absolutely nothing happens. If anyone could help figure out what's wrong with my code it'd be very appreciated.

Comment: downloadProfile is a separate function but isn't called at all

Comment: Thank you so much @NineBerry! Now it does download the file on my device, but it just replaces the `reader.readAsDataURL(blob)` part with `undefined`, do you happen to know a fix?